# Update attribute based on wildcard match of another attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML portion that I am trying to transform with an XSL file.

XML File Sample:

```
<data>
  <KEY name="B1F" value="Smith" />
  <KEY name="B1L" value="Johnson" />
  <KEY name="B2F" value="Nancy" />
  <KEY name="B2L" value="Drew" />
  <KEY name="B1Phone" value="123-456-7890" />
  <KEY name="B1SSN" value="123-45-6789" />
  <KEY name="B1Address" value="1234 Highway 102" />
  <KEY name="B2Phone" value="123-456-7890" />
  <KEY name="B2SSN" value="123-45-6789" />
  <KEY name="B2Address" value="1234 Highway 102" />
  <KEY name="B7SSN" value="987-65-4321" />
  <KEY name="B8F" value="George" />
  <KEY name="B8L" value="Lucas" />
</data>
```

Current XSL excerpt:

```
<xsl:variable name="ReplaceLiveDate" select="false()"/>
<xsl:variable name="BDOB" select="1990-01-01"/>
<xsl:variable name="BF">Test Borrower</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="BL">Last Name</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="BPhone" select="5551234567" />
<xsl:variable name="BSSN" select="555112345" />
<xsl:variable name="Address">Test Address</xsl:variable>

<!-- in DATA: output KEY sorted by @name -->
<xsl:template match="DATA">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="KEY">
            <xsl:sort select="@name" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- output KEY verbatim -->
<xsl:template match="KEY">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<!-- Start of the conversion for Live Data to Test
     need to repeat or wildcard for each instance 
<xsl:template match="KEY[@name='B1L']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:when test="$ReplaceLiveDate = false()">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <KEY value="$BL">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='value')] | node()"/>
            </KEY>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>-->
```

1. I would like to be able to test the attribute value for "name" with a wildcard such as "B?L" or "B[1-8]L" since there can be up to 8 instances, but I am unsure how to apply a RegEx to the selected statement - or if this is even possible.
2. I would like to update the value of the `@value` attribute with that of a variable declared at the top of the XSL (currently all variables are set, but the template is only listed for the "B1L" replacement value).

The uncommented portion of the code works without issue, but the commented section is not working as desired.

Expected Results:

```
<data>
  <KEY name="B1F" value="Test Borrower" />
  <KEY name="B1L" value="Last Name" />
  <KEY name="B2F" value="Test Borrower" />
  <KEY name="B2L" value="Last Name" />
  <KEY name="B1Phone" value="5551234567" />
  <KEY name="B1SSN" value="555112345" />
  <KEY name="B1Address" value="Test Address" />
  <KEY name="B2Phone" value="5551234567" />
  <KEY name="B2SSN" value="555112345" />
  <KEY name="B2Address" value="Test Address" />
  <KEY name="B7SSN" value="555112345" />
  <KEY name="B8F" value="Test Borrower" />
  <KEY name="B8L" value="Last Name" />
</data>
```

Thank you in advance for your help in this matter.

Comment: Are you using XSLT2.0? There is no regex support in XSLT 1.0, unless your processor supports it as an extension. -- P.S. Please clarify exactly what the test should be and what is the expected result in each case.

Comment: The xsl version I am using is 1.0, but could possible covert to 2.0 without issue, I believe.

As for expected results, I will add that in above

Comment: Make sure you *can* switch to an XSLT 2.0 processor, otherwise the answers will be a waste of time for all involved.

Comment: it looks like my current processor only supports version 1.  Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your starting point?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@value">
    <xsl:variable name="code" select="translate(../@name, '123456789', '000000000')" />
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$code='B0F'">Test Borrower</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$code='B0L'">Last Name</xsl:when>
            <!-- add more here -->
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is not working for me.  I added this to my xsl and still get the same results...sorted, but no replacements

Comment: I don't see what you did, so I cannot comment on that. You can see my version working here: http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5ER and AFAICS the result is identical to your expected result.

Comment: with the example you have, all data other than the specified B0F and B0L is cleared.  This is not desired.  In addition, I am trying to have the resulting data sorted, which is not happening.

Comment: Well, I said it was a starting point, and there is a `<!-- add more here -->` comment in my stylesheet. Do not  expect me to do all your work for you. As for sorting, your expected output is not sorted. If you want it sorted, then add a template matching `/data` and call `xsl:apply-templates`, with `xsl:sort`, from there.

Comment: I added in my code as Update 3 - xsltransform.net/bFWR5ER/3

Comment: I have tried a number of combinations, but seem to get blank text for value attributes or the conversion does not work.

current version of test is xsltransform.net/bFWR5ER/4

Comment: Pinpoint?  I am unsure how to do that as it either does not translate the desired values, based on attribute "name" value, or it results in blank values for all attribute "value" values except for those explicitly translated.                                I tried adding an otherwise statement to the translation section for value, but that also returned no values.  I have everything else in place for my xsl, except for this transformation.  Maybe I am unclear on how to integrate your solution into my existing xsl.

Comment: @mike I meant I have no time to go over your entire code and look for problems. Pick one specific issue and point to it - for example, the output shows X instead of Y.

Comment: the one issue is the same as initial...need to translate attributes under the Key nodes.  Based on a value of the "name" attribute, convert the value of the "value" attribute to a new value.  Currently this is not working....given the code provided, or with my test modifications.  My test have either been the same as the initial run - get blank text for value attributes other than those listed or the conversion does not work and the original value is listed.  I have completed everything I need except for this.  I removed extra code from and noted my test in the xsl xsltransform.net/bFWR5ER/5

Comment: I am afraid I don''t really understand the problem. For every value you want to change, you need to list its code explicitly in one of the `xsl:when` instances. If there are values you want to keep as is, handle them by using `xsl:otherwise` - see: http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5ER/6

Comment: it appears the                 <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise> was all that was needed, but I could have swore I tried that a number of time with no luck.  Thank you and sorry for the headaches.